# Typescript with material ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use typescript/react with material UI, but without success.
My index.tsx is

```
declare function require(p: string): any;
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

and the react-tap module is simply:

```
declare module "react-tap-event-plugin" {
export default function injectTapEventPlugin(): void;
}
```

I still get an error

> Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on  tag. Remove this prop
>   from the element. For details, see

Answer (score 0):

> I still get an error

Note : This is react warning you about `onTouchTap` being specified on a component that doesn't have support it.

There is a detailed discussion about it in material-ui : https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4670#issuecomment-231603600

## Fix

- Make sure you inject before any calls to render.
- Make sure you have the latest versions of `material-ui` / `react` etc.